# Asynchronous handling of services who provide data and retrieve it via http when necessary

Tags: angularjs, http, asynchronous, service

I have an angularJS app that utilizes two services to retrieve data from a DB.

> session.js

```
angular.module('RiskAssessment').service('session', ['dbInterface', function(dbInterface) {
this.getBatches = function () {
    if (!this.batches) {
        console.log("Retrieved Batches");
        var that = this;
        return this.pullBatches().then(function (data) {
            that.batches = data; //Is this EVEN possible?
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Didn't retrieve Batches");
    }
    return this.batches;
};
this.pullBatches = function () {
    return dbInterface.pullBatches(this.getUserId());
};}]);
```

> dbInterface.js

```
        pullBatches: function(userId){
            return $http.post('db_queries/get_batches.php', userId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("get_batches.php POST Result: ", response.data);
                    return response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    console.log("Error post");
                });
        }
```

I want to able to get `this.batches` via `getBatches()` if it has already been retrieved and set. Otherwise, I'd like to use `pullBatches()` to retrieve and set `this.batches`. The answer is probably some mix of promises, but I am struggling with this.

Thank you for reading!

**EDIT ::**

> How do I set `this.batches` within a `.then()` of my call to `.pullBatches()`?

```
this.getBatches = function(){
    if(!this.batches) {
        console.log("Retrieved Batches");
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred = this.pullBatches().then(function(data){
            //this.batches = data;  <---------------------------- HERE
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }else{
        console.log("Didn't retrieve Batches");
    }
    return this.batches;
};
```

**EDIT 2 ::**
With great help from @Jahirul_Islam_Bhuiyan I fixed my issue.

```
this.getBatches = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(!this.batches){
        console.log("Retrieved Batches");
        dbInterface.pullBatches(this.getUserId()).then(function(payload){
            deferred.resolve(payload.data);
            service.setBatches(payload.data);
        });
    }else{
        console.log("Didn't retrieve Batches");
        deferred.resolve(this.batches);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};

this.setBatches = function(batches){
    this.batches = batches;
};
```

> In Controller...

```
        session.getBatches().then(function(data){
            //console.log("getBatches.then() : " + JSON.stringify(data));
            $scope.batches = data;
        });
```

I now have a much greater understanding of `promises`!

Comment: use $q to ensure promise. call resolve method in both return from dbInterface with data and return from cache. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Is it true that `$http` post returns a promise? In that case, wouldn't I remove the `.then()` from dbInterface; and just have them in the cache and return from cache?

Comment: yes, $http post returns a promise, you can do as  var deferred = $q.defer(); and later, deferred =$http post();

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. Can you look at my EDIT for slightly revised code. I don't have the promises figured out yet, but I still don't understand how I can set `this.batches` within a `.then()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
this.getBatches = function(){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(!this.batches) {
        console.log("Retrieved Batches");

        this.pullBatches().then(function(data){
           deferred.resolve(data);
        });
    }else{
        console.log("Didn't retrieve Batches");
        deferred.resolve(this.batches);
    }
   var promises = [
            deferred.promise
        ];
    var promise = $q.all(promises);
        return promise;
};
```

hope this help

Comment: Thank you so much! You're helping me understand this! But I am getting an odd error with this code, saying that `deferred.resolve` is not a function. I have $q correctly injected...

Comment: i hv edit the code. No need to assign deferred from $http.